# How do I find transfer function of a discrete-time system when its state-space form is given?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems, signal-processing, systems-theory

I read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_space_representation#Canonical_realizations) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realization_%28systems%29) Wikipedia pages, but both of them are explaining continuous-time systems. My question is about discrete-time case.

For example, given the state-space equations of the second order, single input, single output discrete-time system:

$$ \begin{array}{lccrccr}
\mathbf{x}[n+1] &=& \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix} & \mathbf{x}[n]
&+& \begin{bmatrix} b_{1} \\ b_{2} \end{bmatrix} & u[n]
\\
y[n] &=& \begin{bmatrix} c_{1} & c_{2} \end{bmatrix} & \mathbf{x}[n]
&+& d & u[n]
\end{array} $$

How do I find the transfer function (i.e.; $H(z) = \dfrac{Y(z)}{U(z)}$) of this system?

Comment: In exactly the same way with the continuous time case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a MIMO system given in the state-space form 
$$x[n+1]= A x[n] + B u[n]$$
$$ y[n] = C x[n] + D u [n] $$

The transfer matrix is given by $H(z) = C (zI-A)^{-1} B + D$, and $Y(z) = H(z) U(z)$.

See the derivation [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/MIMO_Systems).

Note for the SISO case, it degenerates the the same thing as a scalar system.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated on the [Wikipedia article for the transfer function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function), the usual substitute for the Laplace transform for discrete time systems is the [Z transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform).